# Does Capitalization Make Sense in This Context

Tags: capitalization

I have a lot of experience as a content writer and did a lot of fiction writing in my past; Things like the Onion's rules on semi-colons make me giggle endlessly. I'm out of SEO and working as a programmer now, but I got roped into editing a lot of the stuff that comes from our SEO firm. So this sentence came across my desk today and I honestly can't decide whether or not it's justified. What do you guys think?

> Learn more about [our company name here], the premiere satellite Internet Company.

Our content writer over there, who has made quite a few grammatical mistakes in the past, corrected the lower-case company to Company. Based on the rules I'm seeing, I can't find support for it. Thoughts?

**Edit:**
I should also clarify, this is sentence not part of a title.

Comment: I don't see a reason to capitalize it here. The word "company" might be capitalized if it's a part of a full company name (e.g."The Jones Company"), in this case it is not (maybe the editor was inattentive and thought "Internet company" was a full name)

Comment: That was definitely what I was thinking. To be honest, I want to give the kid the benefit of the doubt, but, for a content writer, he has some pretty terrible grammar.

Comment: SEO means what?

Comment: Search Engine Optimization. It has to do with tweaking a website so that Google indexes it more highly because people find it more useful than your competitors' websites. A lot of an SEO's job includes content writing.

Comment: It was correct, expected, understandable and justified to use capitals for the words *Internet* & *Company* in the given context. The phrase is well-recognized as a 'synonym' for Internet Service Provider' (ISP) -- the firm in question is not an 'internet company' or an 'Internet company', it's an 'Internet Company'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's an attempt at making Google pick up "Internet Company" as a title, rather than as two words of a phrase, in order to promote your company for the search term "internet company".

It's not grammatically justified, as you are not called "Internet Company" and "Internet Company" is not a commonly used term to name your practice.

Also, it won't work anyway.  Google's system no longer puts much weight on capitalisation/capitalization, due to people trying to introduce phrases using this technique.

Comment: Yeah, I'm in total agreement with you there. I've got two years' experience and I feel like I'm teaching our SEO firm half the time. I don't want to be responsible for it, but a lot of the time I have to be.